# How to specify indentations on multiline parameter lists in IntelliJ Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

This has been bothering me for a while, but I can't seem to figure out how to change this formatting.  Let's take a case class as an example:

[image: How I like my code formatted]

I prefer two tabs after a line-continuation; however, IntelliJ seems to force this style:

[image: How IntelliJ wants to format code]

This behavior seems to be controlled by `Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala -> Other -> Alternate indentation for constructor args and parameter declarations`, which specifies a minimum of 0 spaces, and that simply brings the arg list inline with the opening parentheses.  This isn't a big deal by itself, but whenever I copy/paste blocks of code, it reformats everything and I have to go back and shift-tab ad nauseam.  Is there a style field that I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: I suppose you know your preferred style violates Scala Style Guide Docs, but anyway here they are: https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html I have my own preferrences too but try to stick to the style guide unless the question is not addressed. It makes it easier for other Scala programmers to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also look into [scalari-form plugin](https://github.com/scala-ide/scalariform). It gives you much more and IDE independent. You are particuliary interested in *alignArguments=true* and if I remember correctly defaults should make the indentation as you want.

*Note, that it formats code after some sbt task, for instance `sbt test`, not when you press `Ctrl+Alt+L` or similiar in IntelliJ

Answer (score 9):

There's an Intellij only solution:

Under `Wrapping and Braces`, disable `Method declaration parameters > Use normal indent for parameters`.

Then, under `Other`, enable `Alternate indentation for constructor args and parameter declarations` and set to the number of spaces you want to indent from the declaration level (in your case 4).

Comment: This didn't work for me in ini Ultimate 2020.3. Deselecting "Indent first parameter if on new line" did work.

Answer (score 1):

You want "Align when multiline" checked in the code style settings

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `Align when multiline` under `Method call arguments` doesn't seem to work.  It also changes the alignment behavior of braces.

Comment: There are items: method call for method call, and method declaration for declarations.